# Enum value converting to null in constructor?

Tags: java, enums, bukkit

I have an object which I want to instantiate with an enum value. I do this in the following way:

```
Nation gaul = new Nation("gaul", Color.GREEN, 10, ChatColor.DARK_GREEN, Material.GREEN_WOOL, org.bukkit.ChatColor.DARK_GREEN, Statics.NORTH, Type.SWAMP);
```

The enum value in this case is `Type.SWAMP`

During object instantiation, however, the `Type` value is somehow being converted to `null`

```
public Nation(String nationName, Color color, int id, ChatColor chatColor, Material woolMaterial, org.bukkit.ChatColor bukkitChatColor, String ramSwingDirection, Type biomeType) {
//stuff
this.biomeType = biomeType;
System.out.println(biomeType + " is the value of the passed enumValue");
}
```

output in console:

```
[00:12:53] [Server thread/INFO]: null is the value of the biomeType
[00:12:53] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling nationsatwar v1.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The validated object is null
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a99063f- 
c9d7c16]
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:178) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-a99063f- 
c9d7c16]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.entity.CraftVillager.setVillagerType(CraftVillager.java:57) ~ 
[server.jar:git-Spigot-a99063f-c9d7c16]
    at net.mcnations.nationsatwar.general.packets.npcs.Architect.spawnEntity(Architect.java:108) ~ 
[?:?]
```

top line states that this value is null after simply being passed into the object's constructor...

This is the javadoc of Type: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Villager.Type.html

> Why is the enum value being set to null during object insantiation?

Comment: Can you post the source of `Type`?

Comment: I don't know, but sounds to me like the error message is being produced in a different spot in the code, no? See, the message in the log is different then the message in the constructor. Feels like the message in the log came from a resource bundle or something, as a result of a "Not Null" validation. One thing that I would watch out for, perhaps, is whether or not serialization and deserialization is involved. Maybe your class is not being serialized/deserialized properly, maybe your enum field is transient. I don't know, just a few things to keep an eye out for.

Comment: Linked it in the question. Also pasting it here: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Villager.Type.html

Answer (score 0):

No, the `Type` value isn't converted to null, but it's just not set.

This is what you are doing :

```java
private Type myType; // declare null variable

public MyClass(Type newType) {
   // never set "myType"
}
```

So, you have to use the given value from constructor, like that :

```java
private Type myType; // declare null variable

public MyClass(Type newType) {
   this.myType = newType;
}
```

Don't forget to do this for all variables.